# Unable to delete conversationMember from a private channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a private channel in a team and added members to it using the Microsoft graph beta API. But I'm not able to remove a member from the channel.

I call this method DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamid}/channels/{channelid}/members/{id}, but I receive this response `"error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid id '{id}' provided.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "11d58a76-d953-49ce-a086-418ce5eea09b",
            "date": "2020-05-29T04:37:21"
        }
    }`

According to the documentation I might be getting this if channel isn't private. But in my case, it is. Also I am able to retrieve the user by calling this: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}.

Does this sound familiar to anyone else? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We can reproduce this issue. We are looking into this.

Comment: Any update to this?

Comment: You are passing the user Id that should not be the case it should be member ID as per documentation.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Will change it accordingly. Thanks.